# First char in an enviroment var is being stripped when using moment in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

Using moment in Prerequest:

```
var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("yyyy-MM-DD");
console.log(yesterday);
var pastDate = yesterday;
pm.environment.set("pastDate", yesterday)
```

Request Body:

```
  "AccountId": 1,
    "StartDate": {{pastDate}}
```

Response:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "StartDate": [
            "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 2. Path 'StartDate', line 7, position 18.",
            "Input string '022-06-26' is not a valid number. Path 'StartDate', line 7, position 27."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
}
```

However when looking at the value in the Enviroment:
pastDate: 2022-06-26

So it seems the first character of the variable is being stripped? Not sure how to address this.

Comment: If you had an object `"StartDate": 2022-06-26` would be `"StartDate": 1990`

Comment: No sorry found the answer and its posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution I found was to put the var inside quotes, as JSON needs to recieve dates inside Quote in order to manipulate the value.